# IE 11 issue with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer

I'm getting an error "Expected identifier" in this code.

Any idea what could be causing this?

It looks like this code is coming from the transpiled version of the `react-dom` node module (the black arrow is pointing to the part which is giving the error.)

[image: desc]

[image]

Comment: That isn't transpiled code.

Comment: What do you mean? This is a library I'm including through npm.

Comment: You need to configure Webpack / Babel to transpile all of your code to ES5.

Answer (score 3):

I know this error `Expected identifier`. It occurs when a javascript keyword like `default` is used as a variable or property. 
Modern javascript engines (like in chrome) has no problem with this issue. But obsolete engines like in the Internet Explorer could have some troubles with reserved words. The engine can't "parse" it.

See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Wrapping these words (like `default`, if used as variable or property) in quotes, will fix (workaround) this problem.

```
// this will fail
obj.default = 42;

// this will work
obj["default"] = 42;
```

But I recommend that you ignore the Internet Explorer and only support the browsers today. Like Chrome, Firefox or Edge (the new IE)
Leave IE behind and look ahead. Most people who still use the Internet Explorer, do not know it better. They have to be guided. Support the anti-internet-explorer-campaign. :D Seriously, make the world a bit better.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that this is created from my React code. How do I make sure the React code creates code compatible for IE 11?

And yes, it's good to leave IE, but sometimes you need to have compatibility for certain clients :)